# Difference between "tab=noanswers" | "questions?sort=unanswered" | "answers:0"

Tags: support

I see at least 3 different ways to view unanswered questions. And they all show different results.

```
tab=noanswers » 37417 hits
```

#### https://superuser.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers

```
questions?sort=unanswered » 71200 hits
```

#### https://superuser.com/questions?sort=unanswered

```
answers:0 » 41247 hits
```

#### https://superuser.com/search?q=answers:0

Why? =)

Comment: Unanswered includes questions which have answers but no up votes on them

Comment: Search results include closed questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### To summarize the comments and to close my own answer

[tab=noanswers » 37417 hits](https://superuser.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers)

- Questions with absolutely no answers

[questions?sort=unanswered » 71200 hits](https://superuser.com/questions?sort=unanswered)

- Questions can have answers with a score of zero

[answers:0 » 41247 hits](https://superuser.com/search?q=answers:0)

- Closed or merged questions without any answer are shown too